# Creating a time series with jfreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

Right now I want to create a time series graph in jfreechart. However the examples online only have charts using classes like "Day", "Month", and so on. So I want to essentially create a XY line chart. However the problem I'm having is that Jfreechart doesn't connect the data points in the order in which they were added. Also it doesn't connect the points in the order of the "X Values". So basically I get a "Z" in my jfreechart.

So my question is, is there a way to change the setting for the jfreechart so that it connects the data points based on the "X values"?

Comment: it's all in the manual - the API will give you excellent hints too

Comment: I've tried looking through the manual but can't seem to find anything specific about this issue

Answer (score 12):

You might have a look at [`org.jfree.chart.demo.TimeSeriesChartDemo1`](https://github.com/jfree/jfree-demos/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/demo/TimeSeriesChartDemo1.java), and the associated [API documentation](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc_old/org/jfree/chart/demo/TimeSeriesChartDemo1.html). A typical command to run the demo might look like this:

```
java -cp lib/jfreechart-1.0.13.jar:lib/jcommon-1.0.16.jar \
org.jfree.chart.demo.TimeSeriesChartDemo1
```

[image]

The example uses [`org.jfree.data.time.Month`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/Month.html) to represent monthly data, but other units are available in [`org.jfree.data.time`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/package-summary.html). See also the approach shown in this related [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/jfreechartdemo), which is based on `TimeSeriesChartDemo1`.