# JFreechart installing newer version

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have been using Jfreechart in a package under development. The JFreechart version being used so far was 1.0.13. Now I'd like to see how it behaves in a newer version, in this case 1.0.17. So, I downloaded the new version and places it in the folder
HOME\jfreechart\jfreechart-1.0.17\

I did not remove the older version which still resides in

HOME\jfreechart\jfreechart-1.0.13\

I changed the classpath accordingly to reference the version 1.0.17 jar files.

I keep getting the errors

:42: package org.jfree.ui does not exist
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;
                   ^
.:49: package org.jfree.ui does not exist
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;
                   ^
51: package org.jfree.ui does not exist
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;
                   ^
.:39: package org.jfree.ui does not exist
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;

and so on. When I change the classpath back to reference v 1.0.13, everything is back to normal and works fine.

The specific classpath references for v 1.0.17 are

HOME%\jfreechart\jfreechart-1.0.17\lib\jfreechart-1.0.17.jar;%ADB_HOME%\jfreechart\jfreechart-1.0.17\lib\jcommon-1.0.21.jar;

The specific classpath references for v 1.0.13 are

HOME%\jfreechart\jfreechart-1.0.13\lib\jfreechart-1.0.13.jar;%ADB_HOME%\jfreechart\jfreechart-1.0.13\lib\jcommon-1.0.16.jar;

I did not delete the older version.

Further details: Windows 8.1 machine, java 1.6, work on notepad++ (not eclipse).

Any suggestions as to proper procedure to upgrate JFreechart?

Thank you

Comment: How are you executing?

Comment: javac foo.java. where foo is the package name.

Comment: I believe there is a way to turn on verbose / debugging for javac

Comment: Try the examples shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2603723/230513) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15307253/230513) with you new version.

Comment: The error suggests that the JVM is having trouble finding the JCommon classes.  Check that jcommon-1.0.21.jar is really at that location, and also check that you don't have some other jcommon reference on your classpath.