# Creating A Line Graph In Java

Tags: java, user-interface, graph, jfreechart

I want to create a line graph in Java using a set of data that I have. The data I am collecting is a persons body weight at certain dates. So, for example, I want the body weight on the x-axis ad date on the y-axis. I have used JFreeChart in order to create this graph, however, it only lets me plot doubles for the x and y values. So for example (10, 6), whereas I want something like this: (75, 14.09.2017).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*Creating a time series with JFreeChart*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2602696/230513);  `TimeSeriesChartDemo1` is included in the distribution.

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.